# How to escape a regexp_replace in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle

I am creating a small replaceParam function for Strings and wanted to be able to escape a replacement, e. g.

```
select regexp_replace('%ABC# %ABC#','%ABC#', 'XXX')
from dual;
```

leads to

```
XXX XXX
```

BUT I want to be able to escape the replacment, e. g. by preceding a \ in front of a string, that would be otherwise replaced.

```
select regexp_replace('%ABC# \%ABC#','<themagicregexp>', 'XXX')
from dual;
```

should lead to

```
XXX \%ABC#
```

I tried the non-matching character list, but this doesn't work.

```
select regexp_replace('%ABC#abc\%ABC#','<themagicregexp>', 'XXX')
from dual;
```

should lead to

```
XXXabc\%ABC#
```

In addition because someone mentioned it: I can't go with word boundaries, since this should work also:

```
yoyo%ABC#yoyo
```

I have the feeling this can be done in one regexp, but I just don't see it?

Comment: What happens if your input looks like `'%ABC# \\%ABC#'`?

Comment: Are you trying to direct me into a design flaw of my idea or what's the purpose of your question?
At the moment the result is XXX \\XXX, since I don't escape in any working way.

Comment: I try to figure out what you expect to happen in this edge case. The behavior of a solution should still be defined for that case, since "there will never be input like this" is not a good assumption.

Comment: I would expect the following: XXX \\%ABC#, but I should check this edge case. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work provided you don't have an input that looks like `%ABC#%ABC#`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '%ABC#abc\%ABC#', '((^|[^\])(\\\\)*)%ABC#', '\1XXX' )
FROM DUAL;
```

This will either match:

- The start of the string `^` or a non-slash character `[^\]` followed by any number of pairs of slash characters then, finally, the characters `%ABC#`. This will match `%ABC#`, `\\%ABC#`, `\\\\%ABC#` and so on but will not match `\%ABC#`, `\\\%ABC#`, `\\\\\%ABC#` where there is a slash escaping the `%` character.

The replacement includes the first capture group as the expression can match a preceding non-slash character and pairs of slashes and these need to be preserved in the output.

---

**Update**

This gets a bit complicated but it will do repeated matches:

```
WITH Data ( VALUE ) AS (
  SELECT '%ABC#%ABC#' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ( SELECT LISTAGG(
                  REGEXP_REPLACE( COLUMN_VALUE, '((^|[^\])(\\\\)*)%ABC#$', '\1XXX' ),
                  NULL
                ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY NULL )
         FROM   TABLE(
                  CAST(
                    MULTISET(
                      SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR( d.value, '.*?(%ABC#|$)', 1, LEVEL )
                      FROM    DUAL
                      CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( d.value, '.*?(%ABC#|$)' )
                    AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
                  )
                )
       ) AS Value
FROM   Data d;
```

It uses a correlated sub-query to split the string into sub-strings that end with `%ABC#` or the end-of-string (this is the bit inside the `TABLE( CAST( MULTISET( ) .. ) )`) and then re-concatenates these sub-strings after performing the replacement on the end of each sub-string.

Comment: This works, thank you. I still have to figure out why, but it helps a lot! edit: You helped me to grasp backreferences for the first time...

Comment: @bitschnau Explanation of the regex added. The `(\\\\)*` part addresses the comment from @Tomalak on your question.

Comment: Why is %ABC#%ABC# not replaced to XXXXXX, since # is a non-backslash character to me like is X if the first occurence is replaced before proceeding and looking for more patterns?

Comment: It will start looking for a repeated match following the first match but since it is not at the start of the string it cannot match `^%ABC#` and must match a non-slash character and then `%ABC#` - so it will match the first instance but can't match an immediately succeeding second instance.

Comment: Obvious, if you think it through. Wow, that's a real flaw in the regexp implementation, if you ask me. It should always check the whole string and remember, what occurences are already found, since the finding of an occurance changes the following behaviour of the search. Exclude something from the search pattern is always somehow different in regexp it seems to me.

Comment: @bitschnau Updated with a query that will handle consecutive matches but it's not a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

I like a simpler approach:

```
select replace(
         regexp_replace(
           replace('%ABC# \%ABC#','\%','~~')
           ,'%ABC#', 'XXX')
         ,'~~','\%')
from dual;
```

Note, however, that a regular expression is not needed in this particular case - this works just as well:

```
select replace(
         replace(
           replace('%ABC# \%ABC#','\%','~~')
           ,'%ABC#', 'XXX')
         ,'~~','\%')
from dual;
```

Comment: `%ABC#~~%ABC#` goes to `XXX\%XXX` when it should be `XXX~~XXX` and `\\%ABC#` goes to `\\%ABC#` when it should go to `\\XXX`.

Comment: @MT0 it's just an example - you would use a substitution string that would never appear in real text. I just used `~~` as an example. Also, the q never specified anything special about `\\\`, but this could also easily be replaced using the same technique if necessary.

Comment: The `\\ `, `\\\\ `, `\\\\\\ ` was clarified in comments. Can you give an example of how it can "easily" be replaced?

Comment: You use the `replace` function to replace them with something else. Also, you don't get fussy about it working in 100% of cases - just the range of cases that your application needs to cater for :)